# Convert comma's into periods js

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to make a calculation but it obviously wont calculate with ',' in the numbers. I want to change these vars and make the ',' into '.' using javascript

oldSum.value = '48,35'
newSum.innerHTML = '€43,40'

```
            var oldSumPre = oldSum.value;
            var oldStripped = oldSumPre.replace(/,/g, ".");

            var newSumPre = newSum.innerHTML;
            var newStripped = newSumPre.replace(/,/g, "."); 
            bedrag.innerHTML =  oldStripped - newStripped;
```

Is what Im doing right now.. but it changes bedrag.innerHTML into NaN

Comment: The js replace function but I read  that there were some issues when you'd use that..

Comment: no issues if you use it correctly.. but you do not show how you use it..

Comment: Idk I can't find that thread anymore @mvw

Comment: Also why is this question getting so many downvotes? There's only 1 other topic about this.

Comment: From [the Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Comment: Fair nuff Frxstrem, I updated my question.

Comment: Thanks Mvw, I found out there's a € symbol in one of the strings..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "R,e,p,l,a,c,e";
var res = str.replace(/,/g, ".");

alert (res);
```

Comment: Can you see what I'm doing wrong? (I updated my post)

Comment: It is because of your euro sign in one of the values. Place the euro sign out of your javascript is the easies fix. Maybe a separate <span>. You do some math, but it returns Not A Number because of the euro sign. Also if you want to do math it advised to just assign numbers to your variables and not strings as you do. The quotationmarks indicate a string. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bg12hrbk/

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your variable is vNum. You need to replace all commas with '.' using this

```
vNum = vNum.replace(",", ".");
```

Answer (score 1):

In general you could use a localization / internationalization library, which will solve some other tasks you are likely to run into as well.

For example this one:

https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/doc/api/number/parse-number.md

Snippet:

```
Globalize.locale( "es" );
Globalize.parseDate( "3,14" ); // 3.14
```